# How to store API response in state And pass this response value to another screen as params in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have created A screen. Where I am getting response from API. but now I want to store that response in state. and I want to send that value to another screen by navigation params.
my response is like this ->

```
Array [
  Object {
    "phpid": 10,
  },
]
```

here is my code

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={

    };
}

fetch('https://xuz.tech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/t_details?query=', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify([{"==some values=="}])
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
     console.log(response)
      return response.json();


render(){

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      color="black"  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("FormItems",{i want to send value to formitems})} />
    </View>
)}
```

Comment: Are you using react-navigation? If so, which version?

Comment: yes 4.4.3 i using raect navigation version

Comment: I have send value But This was unique I dont store from response to state and use it before

Answer (score 2):

Set your state once you receive your response, then use your state as params when navigating. Once your fetch has been resolved:

```
this.setState({ response: response.json() });
```

Sending params to another screen is fairly simple, you just need to pass an object as the second parameter to navigate.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('FormItems', {
  form: this.state.response,
});
```

The receiving component will then need to read those params:

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
       <Text>{JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('form', 'some default'))}</Text>
    }
}
```

A full explanation on how to use params with react-navigation v4 can be found here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params

Comment: But How to store response in state

Comment: what should i put instead of some defaut

Comment: navigation.getParam will return null if it can't find the parameter you are looking for. Replace 'some default' with data that you could use if this is the case, otherwise you can do the null check before continuing (if the data is absolutely required for your component to function)

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this. first initialise the state and when you get data from api set the data in state and when button press pass the data to new screen in params.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    export default class Example extends Component {
      state = {
        data: [], // initialize empty state
      };
    
      componentWillMount() {
        this.requestData();
      }
    
        requestData = () =>{
          fetch('https://xuz.tech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/t_details?query=', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                  body: JSON.stringify([{"==some values=="}])
          })
          .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
          .then(function(response) {
         this.setState({
          data:response //set data in state here
         })
          })
        }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button
              color="black"
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('FormItems', {
                  data: this.state.data, // pass data to second screen
                })
              }
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: That wasn't posted while I am answering your question. Anyways if you get the right answer goodluck!